# "Can't load plugin: %s:%s" % (self.group, name) sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:postgres how do i go about

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

```
app = Flask(name) app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"]='postgres://lrmblnrgliqize:f68a5084a90b05e68c1aba33d945417a1c7891317bcffd11ea7f4071f93481d1@ec2-34-198-31-223.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d8khg822mrebg9' ''' app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']=False

db=SQLAlchemy(app)

from flask import Flask, request

from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse

import nltk

import numpy as np

import tensorflow

import tflearn

import pickle

from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

import os

''' ''' absl-py==0.12.0 astunparse==1.6.3 cachetools==4.2.1 certifi==2020.12.5 chardet==4.0.0 click==7.1.2 Flask==1.1.2 Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1 flatbuffers==1.12 gast==0.3.3 google-auth==1.28.0 google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.3 google-pasta==0.2.0 greenlet==1.0.0 grpcio==1.32.0 gunicorn==20.0.4 h5py==2.10.0 idna==2.10 importlib-metadata==3.7.3 itsdangerous==1.1.0 Jinja2==2.11.3 joblib==1.0.1 Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2 Markdown==3.3.4 MarkupSafe==1.1.1 nltk==3.5 numpy==1.19.5 oauthlib==3.1.0 opt-einsum==3.3.0 Pillow==8.1.2 protobuf==3.15.6 pyasn1==0.4.8 pyasn1-modules==0.2.8 PyJWT==1.7.1 pytz==2021.1 regex==2021.3.17 requests==2.25.1 requests-oauthlib==1.3.0 rsa==4.7.2 six==1.15.0 SQLAlchemy==1.4.2 tensorboard==2.4.1 tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.0 tensorflow==2.4.1 tensorflow-estimator==2.4.0 termcolor==1.1.0 tflearn==0.5.0 tqdm==4.59.0 twilio==6.54.0 typing-extensions==3.7.4.3 urllib3==1.26.4 Werkzeug==1.0.1

wincertstore==0.2 wrapt==1.12.1 zipp==3.4.1 '''
```

i get the error when i call
**db.create_all()** in the terminal
i have done every thing  but still the error

Comment: I think you need one of the following listed modules installed: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html I have experience with `psycopg2`; and recommend you install that one, unless you have experience with one of the others.

Comment: I have pip installed the modules but still the error

Comment: It worked fine when I replaced the URL of the heroku database to the one on my postgreSQL

Comment: rfkortekaas it does solve the problem how could i know that after like 4 days stress trying to figure the problem thanks man